# google charts adding $ before short vaxis format

Tags: google-visualization

I want to use the$ as a prefix for my vAxis but with the short formatter , but i was unsuccesfull , can it be done without implementing your own format ? , my chart code is :

```
 options = {
                title: arr[0][0],
                titleTextStyle: { fontSize: '12', color: '#666' },
                colors: ['#50c0ed'],
                backgroundColor: { fill: 'transparent' },
                height: 220,
                width: '100%',
                is3D: true,
                fontSize: '11',
                pointSize: '20',
                seriesType: 'bars',
                hAxis: { format: '$###,###,###.00' },
                vAxis: { format: 'short' },
                vAxes: {
                    0: {
                        viewWindowMode: 'explicit',
                        gridlines: { color: 'transparent' },
                    },
                    1: {
                        gridlines: { color: 'transparent' },
                        format: '###,### Sales'
                    },
                },
                series: {
                    0: { targetAxisIndex: 0 },
                    1: { targetAxisIndex: 1, type: 'line', color: '#f3a600' },
                },
                chartArea: { width: '100%', height: '60%', top: '40', left: '65', right: '10' },
                tooltip: { textStyle: { color: '#333', fontSize: '11' } }
            };

            formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({ pattern: '$###,###,###,###.##' });
            formatter.format(data, 1);
            chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(container[0]);

            var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
            view.setColumns([0, 1, 2,
                {
                    calc: "stringify",
                    sourceColumn: 2,
                    type: "string",
                    role: "annotation"
                }]);
```

so i want the vAxes to have $ as a prefix like $1.5B.

Comment: this can be accomplished by using custom `vAxis.ticks`, otherwise, would need to manually change the labels using script when the chart's `'ready'` event fires...

Comment: Problem is i dont rly wanna put custom ticks because if don't alway know if i have milions or bilions ther or what s the value i neeed betwen scales , so i need something more dinamic

Comment: are you ok with changing the chart's svg manually?